# Посоветуйте корректный подход

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle19c

Доброго времени суток!

Имеется набор данных (таблица / результат запроса / etc):

| item_id | arg1 | arg2 | arg3 | arg4 | arg5 | arg6 | arg7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 5 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 1 | 7 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | 0 | 9 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 5 | 0 | 2 | 7 | 5 | 1 | 1 | 0 |

Необходимо в результате запроса вернуть отчёт по этой таблице:

| / | arg1 | arg2 | arg3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **arg4** | sum() with where clause by arg6 | sum() with where clause by arg7 | count() with where clause by arg7 |
| **arg5** | sum() with where clause by arg6 | sum() with where clause by arg7 | count() with where clause by arg7 |

В MS SQL для таких отчётов раньше пользовался возможностями MSSAS, т.к. он (MSSAS) был на этом сервере оправдан количеством отчётов (порядка 50 отчётов, без учёта пользовательских).

На текущем проекте применение OLAP не оправдано, т.к. поднимать его ради одного отчёта не совсем выгодно.

В связи с этим вопрос - как реализовать построение указанного отчёта без использования Oracle OLAP?

Моё предположительное решение:

Пока в голову приходит только использование конвеерной функции, которая внутри себя будет вычислять значения для каждой ячейки каждой строчки и возвращать результат, но есть подозрения, что я верчу диван не в ту сторону и есть более простые решения.

Версия Oracle - 19c

Comment: Общий подход - условная агрегация.

Comment: @Akina Спасибо за комментарий. По запросу "условная агрегация" поиск выдаёт примеры использования обычных функций (sum / count / etc), без уточнения, что такое "условная". Не могли бы Вы поделиться описанием отличий условной агрегации от обычной. Спасибо!

Comment: `SUM(amount)` - это обычная агрегация. `SUM(CASE WHEN year = 2021 THEN amount ELSE 0 END)` - это условная. Т.е. считается не агрегат по всему набору записей, а только по тем, для которых выполняется условие.

Comment: Оформите пожалуйста отдельным постом, чтобы пометить Ваш ответ как верный! Спасибо огромное!

Comment: Да ну, чего тут оформлять... если хотите, напишите самоответ, и в общем (вроде моих комментариев), и в частности (Ваш итоговый запрос).